# How to call an external URL or SAP interface in Activiti script-task？

Tags: activiti, script-task

I have a requirement that I need to call an external URL (or SAP interface) in the script task to further manipulate the database. I don't know if it can be achieved? I have read a lot of information and there are no related examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, but I would recommend not to use a script task. You better try with a JavaDelegate if you are using Activiti 5.x or 6.x and with a Connector if you are trying the new Activiti Core 7 Beta1. 
https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#serviceTaskCallActivitiService